# Typescript reference directive for single object

Tags: typescript

Usually, when using the `/// <reference .../>` directive in Typescript, the types are added globally. Is there a way to add the types to an object instead?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Types are available across all your files, it doesn’t make sense to have “local types” although you can use modules to make code available only after importing. What do you hope to achieve?

Comment: I am importing a module into the object with a special require function (I can not use regular TS imports). My problem is, that this special require function does not provide the types and I have to add them manually.

Comment: To get a meaningful answer you will have to provide your code, preferably in such a way that we can reproduce your error. We cannot guess what your `special require function` looks like or how it works 